# Trouble implementing a custom list into custom array list into custom array adapter all from jsoup

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, jsoup, listadapter

The title sounds a bit confusing, but I'm parsing information from a website and storing it in `arraylist<string>`. Once I get `ArrayList<String> mPictures = new GetTeachers().execute("div.post_thumb_clean img", "src").get();` to store the results of the `asynctask` that I'm using, I use `ArrayList<Teacher> = mTeachers` and `mTeachers.add(new Teacher(Splash.mNames, Splash.mEmails, Splash.mPictures));` to implement in my `TeacherAdapter`. The problem is that whenever I run all of this, only one `listitem` shows up instead of the 11 or so that were supposed to. I think the problem occurs in my Teacher.class that I use as a `listitem`. Well, I'm not sure how to phrase all of this since I'm learning on my own and I'm not sure if I have the terminology right, but I'm going to post excerpts from each file necessary below. Thanks!
Also, sorry for the crapload of code, feel free to edit the heck out of it.

AsyncTask (GetTeachers.class)

```
public class GetTeachers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    public static ArrayList<Teacher> mTeachers;
    protected final ArrayList<String> mInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... param) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.androidpolice.com/")
                    .timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
            Elements elements = doc.select(param[0]);
            for (Element element : elements) {
                mInfo.add(element.absUrl(param[1]));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mInfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTeachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
        mTeachers.add(new Teacher(Splash.mNames, Splash.mEmails,
                Splash.mPictures));
    }

}
```

Teacher.class

```
public class Teacher {
    String mName, mEmail, mPicture;

    public Teacher() {

    }

    public Teacher(ArrayList<String> n, ArrayList<String> e, ArrayList<String> p) {

        StringBuilder sbn = new StringBuilder();
        for (String mN : n) {
            sbn.append(mN);
            mName = mN;
        }
        StringBuilder sbe = new StringBuilder();
        for (String mE : e) {
            sbe.append(mE);
            mEmail = mE;
        }
        StringBuilder sbp = new StringBuilder();
        for (String mP : p) {
            sbp.append(mP);
            mPicture = mP;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        mEmail = email;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return mPicture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        mPicture = picture;
    }

}
```

TeacherAdapter.class:

```
public class TeacherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Teacher> {

    Typeface thin;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Teacher> mTeacher;
    private int mViewResourceId;

    public TeacherAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Teacher> teacher) {
        super(ctx, viewResourceId, teacher);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "RobotoThin.ttf");
        mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;

        mTeacher = teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
        Teacher teacher = mTeacher.get(position);
        TextView teachername = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_name);
        TextView teacheremail = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_email);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.teacher_picture);

        teachername.setTypeface(thin);
        teacheremail.setTypeface(thin);
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(getContext());
        AQUtility.setDebug(false);

        teachername.setText(teacher.getName());
        teacheremail.setText(teacher.getEmail());
        aq.id(iv).image(teacher.getPicture(), false, true, 64, R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Except from Splash.class

```
    public static ArrayList<String> mNames, mEmails, mPictures = new ArrayList<String>();
        ...
        mPictures = new ArrayList<String>();
        mNames = new GetTeachers().execute("h3 a", "href").get();
        mEmails = new GetTeachers().execute("h3 a", "href").get();
        mPictures = new GetTeachers().execute("div.post_thumb_clean img",
                "src").get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `onPostExecute()` method of your AsyncTask.

```
mTeachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
mTeachers.add(new Teacher(Splash.mNames, Splash.mEmails,
            Splash.mPictures));
```

Here, you initialize the `mTeachers` list, but only add one `Teacher` object. I am not sure what Splash.mNames, Splash.mEmails and Splash.mPictures are.

Now, in your adapter's `getView()` method, `Teacher teacher = mTeacher.get(position);` works for position `zero`. Since the size of `mTeachers` is `one`, only one item is displayed in your listview.

**Edit 1:**

Let's make some changes to your Adapter. Add the following above `Typeface thin;`:

```
private ArrayList<String> mNames;
private ArrayList<String> mEmails;
private ArrayList<String> mPictures;
```

Next, change the constructor from:

```
public TeacherAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Teacher> teacher)
```

to:

```
public TeacherAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> emails, ArrayList<String> pictures)
```

This will go inside your constructor:

```
    super();

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "RobotoThin.ttf");
    mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;

    mNames = names;
    mEmails = emails;
    mPictures = pictures;
```

Your `getView()` will have the following:

```
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    TextView teachername = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teacher_name);
    TextView teacheremail = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teacher_email);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teacher_picture);

    teachername.setTypeface(thin);
    teacheremail.setTypeface(thin);
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(getContext());
    AQUtility.setDebug(false);

    teachername.setText(mNames.get(position));
    teacheremail.setText(mEmails.get(position));
    aq.id(iv).image(mPictures.get(position), false, true, 64, R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

    return convertView;
```

Remove these lines from the `onPostExecute()` method:

```
    mTeachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
    mTeachers.add(new Teacher(Splash.mNames, Splash.mEmails,
            Splash.mPictures));
```

The purpose if to provide the TeacherAdapter with 3 ArrayList in place of ArrayList. Set your adapter and update it(adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: `Splash.mNames`, `Splash.mEmails`, and `Splash.mPictures` are `ArrayLists` that I created with AsyncTask in my splash screen. I thought that adding the ArrayLists that I created would automatically increase the size of `mTeachers` with since there is more than one item in the `ArrayLists`.

Comment: @TheWizKid95 I can see that you are populating `mInfo`, but not using it. Not sure where Splash.* are get their values from. In any case, I'll post some code above in a few minutes.

Comment: I added some code from Splash.class where I instantiate Splash.* with constructors and the result of `AsyncTask` (`mInfo`)

Comment: @TheWizKid95 That's good. Can you post the code where you initialize and set the adapter?

Comment: `TeacherAdapter adapter = new TeacherAdapter(this, R.layout.teacher_item, GetTeachers.mTeachers);`
`setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @TheWizKid95 Okay, change this to `TeacherAdapter adapter = new TeacherAdapter(this, R.layout.teacher_item, mNames, nEmails, mPictures);`  `setListAdapter(adapter);`.

Comment: I've actually done as your edited post told me to before, but I had no luck. my activity was blank when I tried doing it this way. Not one picture or text. This happened to me again just now when I made the changes you said. Before, I tried [this example](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/) to get the code I had when I posted the question.

Comment: Forgot to ask you to change `public class TeacherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Teacher> {` to `public class TeacherAdapter extends BaseAdapter {` We are extending BaseAdapter in place of ArrayAdapter<Teacher>.

Comment: Nevermind, works perfectly! Thank you very much for the hard work!

Comment: @TheWizKid95 Thanks for the accept & up-vote. Please consider reading up on how to build custom objects. In your case, you came up with the `Teacher` class. Its a custom object. For example, a `Teacher` object should only represent one teacher: hold its name, email and picture. This way, we could have created 10 teacher objects and added them to one list and later on, retrieved the object's name, email and picture. Currently, you are handling 3 lists and not using the Teacher class at all. In any case, slow, but steady! Thanks again.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks again! I'm starting college in the fall for computer science, so I hope I can learn a thing or two! lol